# Sonar cloud UnCoverage Lines is difference compare with code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

When I fix coverage in sonar cloud

the report say that UnCoverage Lines is 1

But I saw red warning in code is so many

How can I config "UnCoverage Lines" it count number of line uncoveraged correctly

Thank guys in advance !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only line 29 is counted as that is the only new line.